# Add Quantity Fields to Variations in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

Is it possible to add quantity fields like: 
[image]

I found a [workaround](http://www.eggplantstudios.ca/woocommerce-product-variation-add-cart-grid/) but it only seems to with one variation attribute.

I need a cumulative effect as shown in the image

Comment: Are you trying to add quantities to product add-ons? Or are each of those items a variable product?

Comment: Each of those are variable products, a customer could look at a combo of T-shirts, Trousers and Sunglasses and order 200 T-shirts, 100 Trousers and 50 Sunglasses (just an example). So it's  a package deal kind of things and a customer may order different quantities of each .

Comment: In your mockup you don't have a way to choose the attributes that will select the specific variation. I think you are basically looking for variable product support in grouped products. Sadly, adding support for variable products is difficult, which is why I have hesitated to add support for them to Mix and Match products. I do believe Bundles and Composites both support having variable products. Maybe one of those would be workable for you.

Comment: @Digamber Did you manage to fix this? I need the exact same thing :) Quantity fields on each variation.

Comment: @dominotrix - unfortunately it's been a while and i don't remember the exact solution. But i ended up ditching variations as an option - we may have gone with a custom approach.